# Validating input to an array

Tags: c

I am trying to validate the input of the array to only allow an input of only one single digit integer (either 2 or 3) at each index of the array. For example `a = [2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3]`. My attempt is below.

```
int main()
{
        int a[10];
        int b;
        bool c= false;
        printf( "Please the 10 values: \n");
        while(c)
        {
            for(b=0;b<10;b++)
            {

                scanf("%d", &a[b]);//enter each value individually
                if(&a[b]==2 || &a[b]==3)
                {
                    c= true;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("please the value");
                    scanf("%d", &a[b]);
                    c= false;
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment the counter b when there is a correct value.
scanf will return the number of items successfully scanned. In this case one.
If scanf does not return one, the else will read a character and then scanf can try again.

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int b = 0;
    printf( "Please the 10 values: \n");
    while(b < 10)
    {
        printf( "enter value for a[%d]\n", b);
        if ( ( scanf("%d", &a[b])) == 1) {//enter each value individually
            if(a[b]==2 || a[b]==3)
            {
                b++;//correct value increment b
            }
        }
        else //scanf failed to read an int
        {
            getchar ( );//read a character and try again
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: When I enter a letter I still get an error. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: I'm also trying to solve the problem using for validating for loops.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the *value*, you have to change your code

```
if(&a[b]==2 || &a[b]==3)
```

to

```
if((a[b]==2) || (a[b]==3))   //no need for address of (&) operator
```

However, for an array like `int a[10];`, using

```
 for(b=0;b<32;b++)
```

will overrun the allocated memory and you'll run into undefined behavior.

That said, the `else` part is not checking the validity of the repeated input. You need to take care of that, too.

Also, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Ahh it was supposed to be 32 at first but I changed it to 10 I'll edit the code now. My mistake sorry

Comment: You are using unnecessary parentheses. Just do `if(a[b] == 2 || a[b] == 3)`